# Reg ex to get a substring within a string with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to extract: d101461b-a280-431c-b2bf-a3b200c6e575 from the below string

> https://training.shop4support.com/Resources/FileStorage/Products\\d101461b-a280-431c-b2bf-a3b200c6e575/St Stephen\u0027s Neighbourhood

I've tried:

```
var formattedGuid = guid.match('\\(.*)/').pop();
```

But because of the special characters such as '/' I'm getting an unexpected token error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to match GUID as such:

`guid.match(/[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){4}[0-9a-f]{8}/)`

So I shortened the following regular expression to match 5 groups of hexadecimal numbers (a group can be matched with `[0-9a-f]{length}`):

`[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}`

In the initial expression we can see some patterns, which can be grouped as well, so now it can be described as follows:

> `[0-9a-f]{8}` - a group of eight numbers
>
> `(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){4}` - four groups of hyphen and four numbers (`?:` doesn't save the match)
>
> `[0-9a-f]{8}` - a group of eight numbers left

Comment: This seems to work although I'm not sure whats going on. Would it be possible to expand on your answer just so I can further understand, thank you

Comment: Just looking at your solution and:

    guid.match(/([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/)

Is what I needed to get it to work

Comment: @WilliamLi I tried to explain how this regex works but I'd recommend you to do more reading about the subject. There are many online tutorials about regular expressions that may help.